# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'req' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have watched a video and I tried to apply the following code

```
# pip install html5lib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice

def get_proxy():
    url = "https://www.sslproxies.org/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    return {'https': choice(list(map(lambda x:x[0]+':'+x[1], list(zip(map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[::8]), map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[1::8]))))))}

def proxy_request(request_type, url, **kwargs):
    while 1:
        try:
            proxy = get_proxy()
            req = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, **kwargs)
            break
        except:
            pass
            return req

r = proxy_request('get', "https://youtube.com")
print(r)
```

I got the following traceback error and I have no clue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Spyder\Demo.py", line 16, in proxy_request
    req = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 309, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 193, in proxy_manager_for
    manager = self.proxy_manager[proxy] = proxy_from_url(
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 492, in proxy_from_url
    return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 429, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Spyder\Demo.py", line 22, in <module>
    r = proxy_request('get', "https://youtube.com")
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Spyder\Demo.py", line 20, in proxy_request
    return req
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'req' referenced before assignment
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

The final code ..

```
# pip install html5lib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice

def get_proxy():
    url = "https://www.sslproxies.org/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    return {'https': 'https://' + choice(list(map(lambda x:x[0]+':'+x[1], list(zip(map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[::8]), map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[1::8]))))))}

def proxy_request(request_type, url, **kwargs):
    proxy = get_proxy()
    req = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, **kwargs)
    return req

for __ in range(10):
    try:
        r = proxy_request('get', "https://api.ipify.org")
    except (TimeoutError, OSError) as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
        continue

    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)
    break
```

Comment: What value do you expect for `req` if any exception got raised in try block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because of missing schema (`https://`) in your proxy returned from your function `get_proxy()` — for example it returns

```
{'https': '183.89.96.57:8080'}
```

instead of the correct

```
{'https': 'https://183.89.96.57:8080'}
```

So please correct your `return` statement in this function — instead of your

```
return {'https':              choice(...)}
```

use

```
return {'https': 'https://' + choice(...)}
```

---

*Note 1:*

You may simplify your other function by moving your loop and `try` ... `except` block into the module level (see `Note 2`):

```
def proxy_request(request_type, url, **kwargs):
    proxy = get_proxy()
    req = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, **kwargs)
    return req
```

(You may include `print(proxy)` and `print(req.status_code)` for testing purpose into it.)

---

*Note 2:*

You may move you loop and `try` ... `except` block from this function into the module level, i.e. when you call this function — instead of your

```
r = proxy_request('get', "https://youtube.com")
print(r)
```

use e.g.

```
for __ in range(10):
    try:
        r = proxy_request('get', "https://youtube.com")
    except (TimeoutError, OSError) as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
        continue

    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)
    break
```

---

*Note 3:*

I tested it and it works — sometimes timeout, sometimes refused connection, but sometime OK.
(In all cases the problem was in the remote server, or in my slow connection.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have updated the code as you guided me. Please have a look at the main post. Now I tried the code three times with no luck to get any working proxy. Is it impossible to get a free working proxy??

Comment: @Yasser, did you trying increasing timeout? It **is** possible to get a free working proxy, I had such luck (but not very often with my slow connection).

Comment: @Yasser, e.g. this proxy worked for me: https://183.89.96.57:8080

Comment: I increased the timeout to 20 and the same .. I had no luck in getting free proxies at all.

Comment: @Yasser, I used timeout=150 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```py
        try:
            proxy = get_proxy()
            req = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, **kwargs)
            break
        except:
            pass
            return req
```

The `return req` statement is inside the exception handler, which means it's executed only if an exception is raised during the call to `get_proxy` or `requests.request`. Either way, these will lead to `req` never being bound, hence `UnboundLocalError`.

I expect you wanted to put the `return req` outside the `while` loop, though I would just replace the `break` with it, doing so leads to more straightforward and resilient behaviour.

Also:

- A bare `except` is a very bad idea as it's going to catch things like keyboard interruption (Ctrl-C), meaning you'll have to go through the task manager when (not if!) your program fucks up.
- When an exception is raised, you just busy loop without even notifying the user of what's happening, without the `UnboundLocalError` it could just keep looping around calling `sslproxies` as fast as it can, that's a good way to get banned for abuse, especially when sslproxies clearly advertises that its proxy list is updated *every 10 minutes*.
- Picking a random proxy in the list is fine, but why are you not storing the list of proxies to pick from? See point above, the list is updated *at most* every 10 minutes and you're not doing any sort of pagination, you're going to get the same list every time. Just fetch the proxies list once outside the loop, then randomly pick a proxy to try from within.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I am so newbie at python. Can you help me with grabbing proxies as list then teach me how to test this list?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a proxy I can recommend to use a bit different approach and maybe try using a python package that try to do what you need.

Just install proxy-requests and read in the documentation for more help

Install it by doing ->
pip install proxy-requests

and send a proxy request by

```
r = ProxyRequests('https://api.ipify.org')
r.get()
```

of course there is a way to send a post request and even change the request headers as you wish

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried `from proxy_requests import ProxyRequests` and tried the lines and got nothing at all. Did you try it?

Comment: I just looked on his code documentation and It worked for me.
https://github.com/rootVIII/proxy_requests

In the bottom of the page you will see an example that he made that I found very helpful!

It is a nice thing because you can play with headers and send post request and also see the proxy that was in use (can be handy sometimes)

Comment: Can you post an example that worked with you to try on my side??

Comment: You can try this for example:

from proxy_requests import ProxyRequests

h = {'User-Agent': 'NCSA Mosaic/3.0 (Windows 95)'}
r = ProxyRequests('https://postman-echo.com/headers')
r.set_headers(h)
r.get_with_headers()
print(r.get_proxy_used())

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have executed the code and waited for about two minutes without any response. This what I am talking about.

Comment: My code also didn't returned any output? because it worked for me...

Comment: I mean the Print line didn't work at all. That means for me it didn't work. Or what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your proxy parameter is equals to None.
That way when you try creating a request there is an error and the request object is not assigned.

If you want to solve this you can do 2 different things:

1. After `proxy = get_proxy()` you can check if it is not None and if it is you can configure a default proxy by yourself.
2. You can try and assign a new request in the except section and return the crated object.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

In your `proxy_request()` function define `req` *before* `try`...`except`, e.g.:

```
def proxy_request(request_type, url, **kwargs):
    req = None  # <------------------------------- Here
    while 1:
        try:
            proxy = get_proxy()
            req = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, **kwargs)
            break
        except:
            pass
            return req
```

---

*The explanation:*

You `try` branch failed before the `req = requests.request(...)` command was reached, so the branch `except` was performed and its `return req` command wanted return unknown `req`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now there are no errors. But I have tried the code several times and all what I got is None. Will there be any luck to get a response?

Comment: @Yasser, it was only hot-fix. Now I'm busy, but if nobody resolves it, I will try to help you.

Comment: @Yasser, your problem is now solved, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64818539/7023590).